# Can a related pair of Models be extended without redefining their relationship?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, orm

How do I extend two models without having to redefine their relations to target the 'new' extended model?

Say I have two related Eloquent model: **Shop** and **Item** in a package.

**Shop** defines a `HasMany` relation to **Item**.
**Item** defines a `HasOne` relation to **Shop**.

Now say I want to extend *both* models in some other package. Maybe something like:

```php
class LuxuryShop extends Shop{
  protected static function booted()
  {
    static::addGlobalScope(new LuxuryScope);
  }
}

// ...
class LuxuryItem extends Shop{
  protected static function booted()
  {
    static::addGlobalScope(new LuxuryScope);
  }
}
```

The problem I have now is that the relations are still pointing to the 'base' model without the new functionality (be it a scope or anything else);

```php
$anyShops = Shop::with('items')->get();
$anyShops->first()->items; // this is a collection of Item model;

$luxuryShops = LuxuryShop::with('items')->get();
$luxuryShops->first()->items; // this is a collection of Item model;
```

Is it possible to get 'LuxuryItem' from 'LuxuryShop's `items` HasMany relation without redefining it in the extended model?

I suspect contextual bindings might have a solution but not quite sure how I'd define it.

Please note that actual use-case is many relations over many models used in different contexts (where each consuming context extends the base model). For only a one-off like this example I'd just go ahead and redefine the relation.

This takes place in Laravel 8

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why don't you use two Traits in order to implements these especial features and use as required in your case, instead of extending your models.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php

Comment: The trait would still need to have the specific 'target' model in it right? That still amounts to redefining it per model.

Comment: I don't understand you, a Trait is an extension on functionality for other class, is the simple mechanism that PHP use to implements some features needed in a Class without modify the class. You can refer to model with $this. Here you have an example from Laravel code where use a Trait precisely in Model.php https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasTimestamps.php.

Comment: You can declare traits for extended features and use in your model class without having to extend your model class, I´m sure you can put all extended features in your ExtendableShop.php and ExtendableProduct.php. Anyway with the information provided, probably there are a better solution via Interfaces, but given that php only support single inheritance, composition is a better strategy than inheritance Imho

Comment: The use case is that we have a repo of Models that only define the table and relations, then many packages that each use these Models in their own context. If we add traits for every consuming packages specific logic the base models will have many possibly conflicting traits. I suspect that a solution might be found in contextual binding but more experimentation required.

Comment: Without knowing anything about your domain, I think that in your case could be applied Strategy Pattern, add complexity to your design but it is very flexible and I think it accommodates to your use case. [Strategy Pattern](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/strategy/php/example)